# How to access HttpServletResponse object in @Around advice

Tags: spring, servlets, model-view-controller, aop, aspectj

I would like to capture the httpResponse object in a logging aspect, so that I can log http return codes centrally for my controller methods.  e.g. something like:

```
    @Around("execution(* ..*Controller.*(..))")
    public Object handleLogging(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

        // start stopwatch
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // HttpServletRequest works no problem 
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

        logger.info("this was the request url", request.getRequestURI());

        // proceed with method
        try {
            retVal = pjp.proceed();
        }
        finally{
            // stop stopwatch
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long duration = endTime-startTime;

            // how do I get the response?
            // this doesn't seem to work, response is null..
            ServletWebRequest servletWebRequest=new ServletWebRequest(request);
HttpServletResponse response=servletWebRequest.getResponse();


            logger.info(appendEntries(securityAuditParameters),
                    "Method={} executionSuccess={} executionTime={}", pjp.getSignature(), response.getStatus(), duration);

        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to get at the HttpServletResponse so I can output my return codes.  I can handle it in the controllers for sure but, would be interested in keeping this all in the aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see the response is not yet formed when the controller is returned. This will be further handed over to the view resolver api of spring before the response is formed.
If your intention is to just log the time taken by appserver to serve a request you may want to look at "`javax.servlet.Filter`" implementation. It gives you handle to all the request/response api and it can be the first and last thing to be executed depending on how you configure your filter chain in web.xml.
Also, Aspect around the controller will not include the time taken for the jsp to be executed. Potentially some taghandlers can add considerable time to your processing after the controller has returned.